# How can I convert nupkg file to zip file when we deploy on windows target machine?

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, gitlab, ansible-template

I am using below playbook

```yaml
- name: service deployment
  hosts: "{{ APP_HOSTS }}"
  vars:
    backup_keep: 2
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name : Ping Server
      win_ping:
      tags:
         - ping

    
    - name: Download NuGet Package
      ansible.windows.win_get_url:
        url: "{{ PKGURL }}/{{ app }}/{{ version }}"
        dest: "{{ PKGFOLDER }}/IdocService.1.0.27.nupkg"
        headers:  
          Authorization: "Basic {{NEXUS_AUTH}}"

    - name: Rename .nupkg to .zip
      ansible.windows.win_copy:
        src:  "{{ PKGFOLDER }}/IdocService.1.0.27.nupkg"
        dest: "{{ PKGFOLDER }}/IdocService.1.0.27.zip"
        remote_src: yes
```

## backups

```yaml
- name: Backup files before stopping app pool
  block:
    - name: print backup folder path
      debug:
        msg: "D:/ansible_runner/backups/{{ APP_SLUG }}/{{ ansible_date_time.date }}"

    - name: Prepare backup folder
      ansible.windows.win_file:
        state: directory
        #path: "D:/ansible_runner/backups/{{ APP_SLUG }}/{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic_short }}"
        path: "D:/ansible_runner/backups/{{ APP_SLUG }}/{{ ansible_date_time.date }}"

    - name: Backup files
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          Copy-Item -Path {{ API_TGT_PATH }}/* `
          -Destination D:/ansible_runner/backups/{{ APP_SLUG }}/{{ ansible_date_time.date }} `
          -Recurse `
          -Exclude Logs*,backup*,backups*,Backup*,Backups*
```

## Deploy

```yaml
- name: stop service - {{ API_SERVICE }}
  ansible.windows.win_service:
    name: "{{ API_SERVICE }}"
    state: stopped

- name: Copy build 
  ansible.windows.win_copy:
    src:  "D:/ansible_runner/temp/{{ app }}.{{ version }}/publish/"
    dest: "{{ API_TGT_PATH }}"
    remote_src: yes

- name: start application pool - {{ API_SERVICE }}
  ansible.windows.win_service:
    name: "{{ API_SERVICE }}"
    state: started
```

## Cleanup Old Backups

```yaml
- name: Get Available backup files
  ansible.windows.win_find:
    paths: "D:/ansible_runner/backups/{{ APP_SLUG }}"
    file_type: "directory"
  register: avl_backups
  
- debug:
    var: avl_backups

- set_fact:
    backups_to_delete: "{{ (avl_backups.files | sort(attribute='lastwritetime', reverse=true) | map(attribute='path') | list)[backup_keep:] }}"

- name: Backups that can be deleted 
  debug:
    var: backups_to_delete
    
- name: Delete backup files
  ansible.windows.win_file:
    state: absent
    path: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ backups_to_delete }}"
```

## Cleanup nexus package

```yaml
- name: Remove Nexus package
  ansible.windows.win_file:
    name: "{{PKGFOLDER}}/{{ app }}.{{ version }}.nupkg"
    state: absent
```

I tried with copy module

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please [edit] the above to make it a [mre]. You will have to remove anything that is not directly related to your problem to keep only the parts that deal with converting your file as you require. You also have to add the result of running the cleaned-up code with any output and error you get. And last, you have to describe what you expect instead

Comment: You can directly use `win_get_url` with `dest: "{{ PKGFOLDER }}/IdocService.1.0.27.zip"`. There is no need to name the file `.nupkg`during the download and rename it afterwards.